# How to use mutate to add column with state names based on the state abbreviation in an existing column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a "STATE" column that contains US state abbreviations only, and I want to add a new column with state names based on the abbreviation given in that row. It seems like there should be an elegant way to use dplyr::mutate and state.name and state.abb. This works well to return the state name:

```
state.name[which(state.abb == "NY")]
```

But how would I use this in mutate? Example dataframe:

```
df_abb <- data.frame(x = 1:5, STATE = c("AK", "AK", "AL", "AR", "CA"))
```

My attempt using mutate, which doesn't work:

```
df_abb_w_name <- df_abb %>%
    mutate(STATE_NAME = state.name[which(state.abb == STATE)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df_abb %>% 
  mutate(state_name = state.name[match(STATE, state.abb)])
```

You can't use the `==` operator the way you were trying to, it wants to compare element-by-element, play around with it to learn more. This won't work if your data has extra abbreviations, such as DC.